# use other custom html elements inside a stenciljs app

Tags: javascript, custom-element, stenciljs

I'm trying to use a couple of custom html elements inside a stenciljs app.  I've done `npm install new-component` and confirmed that it is in the node_modules directory.  In my app.ts I've done `import { defineCustomElements as NewComponentLoader} from "new-component/loader";` and then within the `export default async () => { NewComponentLoader(window); }`.  In app-root.tsx I have `import { NewComponent } from "new-component";` and added  inside the render function.

I also added "node_modules/new-component" to the files array in package.json.

I've stopped the server and done `npm run build` and then `npm run start` a couple of times, but I still get a 404 error because it is looking for the new-component.js files in the build folder.

There are references to new-component in the core-js*.js and dom-*.js files under www/build, but I still get the 404.

Anyone know what I've forgotten?  Was my mistake picking community app when I initialized the stencil app?

Comment: You may have better luck simply loading new-component.js via a script tag in your main HTML file.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would be the way to go.  It means making sure all of the files in node_modules/new-component are copied into build and dist correctly, which is a pain.

Comment: That should be easy (I've done it) - just add a copy task to your output target in stencil.config.ts.